# How to make a texture from the view of the camera live (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, camera

i am making a security camera and a want the view of the camera to display as a texture on a monitor. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't be able to make it happen in real-time, you will need to set your security camera as the active scene render camera, then save the rendered video of it. Then set the texture of your tv screen to that of the video. You could get away with doing a lower sample and lower resolution video if you don't get too close to the screen.

Comment: ok thanks! I will try that.

Comment: Let me know if it goes well